# How does Translate To and/or the Coordinate System work in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, coordinates, translation

When images are clicked, a dropdown window comes and the user can click on one of the many options of where to put the image. However, the second image appears to be off by about 35 and the third image seems about 70 lower. I am using the Image.TranslateTo. How does the coordinate system work in Xamarin Forms and is there a better way to put images in a specific place on the coordinate system?

Comment: What are you talking about?  Do you have any code or screenshots?  Without some context your question is gibberish.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your question accordingly. This will make it possible for someone to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About **[Translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#translation)** method , there are three parameters inside it .

```
image.TranslateTo (TranslationX, TranslationY, millisecond);
```

- TranslationX : Gets or sets the X translation delta of the element.
- TranslationY : Gets or sets the Y translation delta of the element.
- millisecond : how much time need to finish animation (milliseconds).

That means parameter `TranslationX` and `TranslationY` just indicate the **Offset** of `View`, not the `coordinate` .

If I have the xaml code as follow :

```
<Image Source="icon.png" BackgroundColor="Accent" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
<Image x:Name="imageone" Source="imageone.png" BackgroundColor="Aqua" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
<Image x:Name="imagetwo" Source="imagetwo.png" BackgroundColor="Beige" HeightRequest="50" />
<Image x:Name="imagethree" Source="imagethree.png" BackgroundColor="BurlyWood" HeightRequest="50" />
```

The screen shows :(For better to explain, I set the `HeightRequest` and `BackgroundColor` for `Image`.)

[image]

You wiil see from above code , `height` of `imageone/imagetwo/imagethree` all is `50` . And I will get the `X` of `imageone` first after running . It's `180` .Then I will write code for `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` method as follow to translate `imageone` and `imagetwo`.

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tap" + imageone.X +"---"+ imageone.Y);
    imageone.TranslateTo(-180, 0, 1000);
    imagetwo.TranslateTo(0, 100, 1000);
}
```

The effect as follow :

[image]

And the printed logs of `Console` is :

```
14:34:36.621 I/mono-stdout( 4499): Tap180---290.714285714286
14:34:41.171 I/mono-stdout( 4499): Tap180---290.714285714286
```

Then you will found there are two conclusions :

**First** , TranslationX and TranslationY just indicate the `Offset` of `View` .

**Second** , Translation method will not modify the `coordinate` of `View` .